# Find the sum of the binomial coefficients

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Find the sum of the binomial coefficients $(^n_0)+(^n_1)+...+(^n_{n-1})+ (^n_n).$

I'm not good with the binomial theorem but I do know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (^n_k)x^{k} =
(^n_0)+(^n_1)x+...+ (^n_n)x^n.$

Now comparing the binomial coefficients I can see some similarities, but the difference would be that $(^n_{n-1})$ and the $x^n$.

If I just have  $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (^n_k) =
(^n_0)+(^n_1)+...+ (^n_n).$ then all I would be needing would be that $(^n_{n-1})$.

Any help?

Comment: Write the expansion $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (^n_k)x^{k}$

Comment: Set $x=1$ in it.

Comment: The you would get something like this?  $2^n$?

Comment: OK. and the first side is $(1+1)^n$.no?

Comment: You can also try a few examples with a small $n$ and then induce the general formula. Also, that sum is equal to the amount of all subsets with cardinality from 0 to n, of a set with  n elements... which is the cardinality of the powerset, if you have some knowledge of elementary set theory.

Comment: Come on, $\binom n{n-1}$ is in the $\dots$ !

Comment: Yes we would get $(1+1)^n$ which will equal to $2^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (^n_k)1^{n-k}x^{k} =
(^n_0)+(^n_1)x+...+ (^n_n)x^n $?
We need $x=1$ here.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't add the $(1+x)^n$, so it would be then $(2^n)$ right?

Comment: @FernandoFernandez sure, take $x=1$ and we get $2^n$ as the answer to the sum.

Comment: Just out of curiousity how would $2^n$ be denoted in summation form? I struggle with binomial theorem, so i want to understand it a little bit better.

Comment: Why would you want that? We just wrote it as a sum of binomial coefficients. The sum is now simplified to one term.

Comment: I see, do you have any book or website to recommend where I can get more familiar with summation proofs and the binomial theorem?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a set with $\# X =n$, then $\binom{n}{0}$ is the number of subsets with no elements, $\binom{n}{1}$ is the number of subsets with one element and so on. So $\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}$ gives the number of all subsets of $X$ which is $2^n$ since $\# \mathcal P (X)=2^n$.

[This is why some people write $2^X$ for the powerset of $X$ instead $\mathcal P(X)$.]